# What does import React from "react" and import ReactDOM from "react-dom" actually means in simple words?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am just starting with react and I see these two lines:
`import React from "react";`
`import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`I can't figure out what exactly does these two lines do. I see two folders named react and react-dom in the nodes-modules folder but nothing else. Can anyone explain me these two lines word by word in the simplest language possible. Ps- I want to strengthen my fundamentals so I could explain the same to someone else easily.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_specifiers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: It's possible that you find the `import React from "react"` confusing because the imported `React` might not be visibly used in JSX files. However, it is important to understand that JSX files are not Javascript files... they are translated into Javascript that will rely on that imported `React` module, even though this might not be explicitly apparent in JSX files.

Comment: ...although, of late, it appears that react are addressing this apparent inconsistency:  https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each programming language is made by lots of files, unless you can code everything in one place.

So if you want to get some code from another place, in english, it's called import (or include in some other languages).

```
  import React form "react"
```

This line says I import `React` from somewhere else. That's all.

If you interested where it is, then open a folder called `node_modules/react`. As for what you have imported, that's a long story. Once you grow with your programming skills, you will know eventually what you have imported :)

Comment: ``form``. yes, form.